# can we mandate elastic search to treat all numeric field as double

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using dynamic binding while indexing my data. For example

```
{  "a" : 10 }
```

will create the mapping for the field as `long` . While second time while indexing the data may be double `{ "a" : 10.10 }`.  but since the mapping is already defined as long it would index data as long.  The only way to fix this is defined the mapping in advance, which I dont want to do for various reasons.

So my question  - Is there a way I can mandate elastic search to treat all numberic field as `double`.

Comment: I kind of got an answer for this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html . I will try to out and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic mapping template: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html

If it matches as long map it to double:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "integers": {
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I found that in the net just after posting it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Saw your comment about finding solution yourself just after posting my answer :)